# Android: What happens with Alpha users when I promote a apk to beta phase

Tags: android, console, apk, alpha, beta

I have an apk with version code 64 on Alpha group, then I want to promote it to Beta phase. What happens to the users on the Alpha group that haven't downloaded that version yet?
Do they will still be able to update automatically to that version (that will be on Beta for now on)? Or will they get stuck into past version, since into Alpha test I will have no published apk anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

The two interesting points for your case:

- If a beta APK is uploaded with a higher version code than an alpha APK, the alpha version will automatically be deactivated.
- Alpha testing group users are eligible for the alpha, beta, or production version of your app with the highest version code that is compatible with their device.

Comment: So it means that they will fall to the beta version of apk?

Comment: Precisely, until you've added a higher version for the alpha group